# How to make IBM Kitura Framework listen on IPv6 port?

Tags: kitura

I made a web application using IBM Kitura Framework, but the service only listens on IPv4? How to make it listen on both IPv4 and IPv6?

The source code which adds a HTTP server is as follow

```
Kitura.addHTTPServer(onPort: 8090, with: router)
```

And I run `lsof -i:8090` on my Ubuntu Server, the result is

```
COMMAND    PID USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
ServerNew 1731 root    4u  IPv4  24114      0t0  TCP *:8090 (LISTEN)
```

It shows that the 8090 port only listens on IPv4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm the Business Development Manager for Kitura in IBM. Kitura 2 doesn't yet support IPv6. It's supported in Bluesocket and the underlying frameworks, but has not yet been implemented in the socket.create() api. This is in the backlog and will be coming in the not too distant future.

Comment: I'm looking forward to the coming of that day!

Comment: The change isn't too difficult to make, however as we are currently investigating whether to migrate to SwiftNIO which was announced by Apple last week we'll need to evaluate whether making a change to the current API is worth doing at this time. If you join our public slack (http://slack.kitura.io/) workspace we'd happily keep you posted of updates.